# stretchr/testify/assert just giving stack trace, missing actual error message

Tags: go

I have this following test that I would like to convert to use `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` import, what would be best practice to get this done ?
Code as is now:

```
func TestSdk(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    sdk, err := NewSdk(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Unable to get VMware SDK: %v", err)
    }

    defer sdk.GovClient.Logout(ctx)
}
```

> Error: FAIL | --- FAIL: TestSdk (0.00s)
>        |     sdk_test.go:48: **Unable to get VMware SDK: Please set environment variables: HCI_ENDPOINT, HCI_USERNAME and HCI_PASSWORD**
>        | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
>        |    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>        | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x151cc31]
>        | goroutine 6 [running]:
>        | testing.tRunner.func1(0xc00019a100)
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:792 +0x387
>        | panic(0x1642c20, 0x1f46a80)
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
>        | github.com/kubicorn/kubicorn/cloud/vmware/vmwareSdkGo.TestSdk(0xc00019a100)
>        |    /Users/jonma/go/src/github.com/kubicorn/kubicorn/cloud/vmware/vmwareSdkGo/sdk_test.go:51
>   +0x121
>        | testing.tRunner(0xc00019a100, 0x1825b48)
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
>        | created by testing.(*T).Run
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:878 +0x353 FAIL |    github.com/kubicorn/kubicorn/cloud/vmware/vmwareSdkGo   0.019s

This is what I changed to, the problem with this approach is that, error message gets not displayed just some long stack trace

```
func TestSdk(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    sdk, err := NewSdk(ctx)

    assert.Errorf("Unable to get VMware SDK: %v", err)

    defer sdk.GovClient.Logout(ctx)
}
```

> FAIL | --- FAIL: TestSdk (0.00s)
>        | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
>        |    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>        | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x151eecf]
>        | goroutine 6 [running]:
>        | testing.tRunner.func1(0xc00019e100)
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:792 +0x387
>        | panic(0x1645200, 0x1f4aab0)
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
>        | github.com/kubicorn/kubicorn/cloud/vmware/vmwareSdkGo.TestSdk(0xc00019e100)
>        |    /Users/jonma/go/src/github.com/kubicorn/kubicorn/cloud/vmware/vmwareSdkGo/sdk_test.go:57
>   +0x1ef
>        | testing.tRunner(0xc00019e100, 0x1828420)
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
>        | created by testing.(*T).Run
>        |    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:878 +0x353 FAIL |    github.com/kubicorn/kubicorn/cloud/vmware/vmwareSdkGo   0.034s

Here I'm missing the actual error message from the function that was called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `defer sdk.GovClient.Logout(ctx)` try `defer func() { if (ctx!=nil) { sdk.GovClient.Logout(ctx) }`

The second panic is from this defer on an incorrect ctx

(I don't have the vmwareSDK in front of me here, the key thing is to check that the sdk.GovClient.Logout has a valid parameter before attempting it)

Comment: now the `assert.Errorf` if always invoked, how can that be prevented?

Comment: er sorry thught that what you intended!  How about ``assert.NotNilf(t, err, "error message %v", err)``

Comment: this is what I got `FAIL | --- FAIL: TestSdk (1.62s)
     |     sdk_test.go:50:
     |          Error Trace: sdk_test.go:50
     |          Error:       Expected value not to be nil.
     |          Test:        TestSdk
     |          Messages:    error message <nil>`

Answer (score 0):

The error message you quoted is not from the code snippet you posted. But I do see three obvious issues:

1. The first argument of testify's assertions should be `t`, I think when you saw the panic you probably used `nil`.
2. You've not passed the error for testing in, it should be the second argument, even if it is also the fourth argument for the string format.
3. You probably want `assert.NoErrorf`, this will fail when there *is* an error.

Putting this all together:

```golang
func TestSdk(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    sdk, err := NewSdk(ctx)

    assert.NoErrorf(t, err, "Unable to get VMware SDK: %v", err)

    defer sdk.GovClient.Logout(ctx)
}
```